# Google AdMob integration in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I found nowhere an example how to integrate it with swiftui. Does anybody found a tutorial?
The problem is the part with the root controller.

Comment: There's an official guide available now provided by Google: [How to integrate ads with the Google Mobile Ads SDK into your SwiftUI app](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/swiftui).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

in the Apple SwiftUI tutorial - [integration in SwiftUI](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/interfacing-with-uikit)

you can find that how to solve this question with `UIViewControllerRepresentable`

and I create an example like this

```
import GoogleMobileAds
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

struct GADBannerViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
        let view = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)
        let viewController = UIViewController()
        view.adUnitID = "your ad unit id in there."
        view.rootViewController = viewController
        viewController.view.addSubview(view)
        viewController.view.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: kGADAdSizeBanner.size)
        view.load(GADRequest())
        return viewController
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context) {}
}
```

then you can using `GADBannerViewController` in your SwiftUI view's body like that

```
HStack {
    Spacer()
    GADBannerViewController()
        .frame(width: kGADAdSizeBanner.size.width, height: kGADAdSizeBanner.size.height)
    Spacer()
}
```

if you have any questions, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much! Great tip for SwiftUI and AdMob ads.

Comment: What do you think about my implementation? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60200602/ios-swiftui-admob-native-ads-convenience-class

Comment: How to use smart banner size?

Answer (score 7):

To improve on Mcatach and avoid adding the view to the app's root view controller:

```
struct GADBannerViewController: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

@State private var banner: GADBannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)

func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController {
    let bannerSize = GADBannerViewController.getAdBannerSize()
    let viewController = UIViewController()
    banner.adSize = bannerSize
    banner.adUnitID = "ca-pub-ad-id-12345678"
    banner.rootViewController = viewController
    viewController.view.addSubview(banner)
    viewController.view.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: bannerSize.size)
    banner.load(Ads.createRequest())
    return viewController
}

func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context){
    let bannerSize = GADBannerViewController.getAdBannerSize()
    banner.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: bannerSize.size)
    banner.load(GADRequest())
}

static func getAdBannerSize() -> GADAdSize {
    if let rootView = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.view {
        let frame = rootView.frame.inset(by: rootView.safeAreaInsets)
        return GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth(frame.width)
    }
    //No root VC, use 320x50 ad banner
    return kGADAdSizeBanner
}
```

}

The layout code:

```
    private func adSection() -> some View {
    HStack {
        let size = GADBannerViewController.getAdBannerSize()
        Spacer()
        GADBannerViewController()
            .frame(width: size.size.width, height: size.size.height)
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

Comment: nice addition! It's better this way

Comment: What does Ads.createRequest() look like?

Comment: @chitgoks Just GADRequest(), I'll update the answer.

Comment: thank you @PigDogBay. best solution for SwiftUI. Just one thing, it gives a purple message saying This method should not be called on the main thread as it may lead to UI unresponsiveness. Why is that? Even i tried to run the banner.load() inside a dispatch async, still the same.

Comment: @chitgoks Maybe related to this https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/714467

Comment: @PigDogBay thanks for the confirmation. I know it is because of using admob but glad to know it's an issue that will be resolved.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `UIViewRepresentable` instead of `UIViewControllerRepresentable`.

I implemented the Adaptive banner with this code:

```swift
struct AdView : UIViewRepresentable {
    @State private var banner: GADBannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<AdView>) -> GADBannerView {
        #if DEBUG
        banner.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-debug"
        #else
        banner.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-prod"
        #endif

        guard let rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController else {
            return banner
        }
        
        banner.rootViewController = rootViewController
        
        let frame = { () -> CGRect in
            return banner.rootViewController!.view.frame.inset(by: banner.rootViewController!.view.safeAreaInsets)
        }()
        let viewWidth = frame.size.width

        banner.adSize = GADCurrentOrientationAnchoredAdaptiveBannerAdSizeWithWidth(viewWidth)

        banner.load(GADRequest())
        return banner
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: GADBannerView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<AdView>) {
    }
}
```

Then you can call on your Stack using

```swift
AdView().frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 300)
                .frame(width: kGADAdSizeBanner.size.width, height: kGADAdSizeBanner.size.height)
```

Comment: Exactly why is is better than UIViewControllerRepresentable?

Comment: Because you want to add a view, not a view controller, to your view controller.

Comment: I tried your solution, but banner is misplaced - not only covering status bar, but it's even a little higher.

Comment: Working great! Thanks a lot 

Comment: This is how I have implemented banner ads, but I find that I have thousands of requests.  For example, on AdMob I see 6.35K requests for only 153 impressions because it's constantly calling updateUIView.  Is that ok?

Comment: hi @mcatach using kGADAdSizeBanner.size.width does not occupy the whole width of the screen. why is that? I did try to use .infinity and it worked but it gave out a purple message in xcode saying non-finite something.