# SwiftUI - Banner Ads from Google AdMob not displayed anymore since kGADAdSizeBanner deprecation and Google Mobile Ads SDK 8.13.0

Tags: ios, swiftui, admob, banner-ads

A while back I implemented successfully the code in SwiftUI to show banner ads. Since my app wasn't on the AppStore yet, I could only display test ads. Then, I added my app to my Google AdMob profile, and it has been verified (almost 2 weeks ago). So I updated the pods (now Google Mobile Ads SDK is on version 8.13.0), and I waited until today to see if the verification process was maybe taking longer than expected. However, now I can't see proper ads nor test ads. Here is my code:

GoogleAdsManager.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import GoogleMobileAds
import UIKit


struct Banner:View{

  let testIdGoogleBanner = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"
        
    var body: some View{
        HStack{
            Spacer()
            BannerAdView(bannerId: testIdGoogleBanner)
            .frame(width: 320, height: 50, alignment: .center)
            Spacer()
        }
        
    }
}

struct BannerAdView : UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var bannerId : String
    let banner = GADBannerView(adSize: GADAdSizeBanner)
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator { Coordinator(self) }
    
    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<BannerAdView>) -> GADBannerView {
        banner.adUnitID = bannerId
        banner.rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController
        
        banner.load(GADRequest())
        banner.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        return banner
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: GADBannerView, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<BannerAdView>) { }
    
    class Coordinator : NSObject, GADBannerViewDelegate {
        var parent : BannerAdView
        init(_ parent : BannerAdView) { self.parent = parent }
        
        func adViewDidReceiveAd(_bannerView: GADBannerView) {
            print("Ad received")
        }
        func bannerView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: Error) {
            print("Error when receiving ads: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    
}
```

MyApp.swift

```
import SwiftUI
import GoogleMobileAds
import AppTrackingTransparency

@main

struct MyApp: App {

    
init() {
    if ATTrackingManager.trackingAuthorizationStatus == .notDetermined {
    } else {
        ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { status in
            GADMobileAds.sharedInstance().start(completionHandler: nil)
        }
    }
    }
var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView()
       }
        }
 }
```

And then in the ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI
import GoogleMobileAds
import UIKit
import AppTrackingTransparency
import AdSupport 

struct ContentView: View {

var body: some View {
ZStack {
//Other elements
VStack {
Spacer()
Banner()
}
.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
}
.onAppear {
ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization { status in
            switch status {
            case .authorized:
                print("Authorized")
                print(ASIdentifierManager.shared().advertisingIdentifier)
            case .denied:
                print("Denied")
            case .notDetermined:
                print("Not Determined")
            case .restricted:
                print("Restricted")
            @unknown default:
                print("Unknown")
            }
        }
}
}
}
```

I have implemented the Info.plist exactly [as stated here](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/quick-start), I only changed the GADApplicationIdentifier with my AdMob app ID. The other thing that I changed are the kGADAdSizeBanner, which were marked as deprecated, and so I changed them to GADAdSizeBanner.

In the Ad implementation (in the BannerAdView) there's also a Coordinator, which in the console prints "Error when receiving ads: No ad to show".

Other questions on "No ad to show" were suggesting to wait for the app approval, or to wait for a few days after it has been approved, but I waited and nothing changed. I have tried other solutions/implementations, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67870764/google-admob-banner-ads-are-not-working-in-swiftui), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57641603/google-admob-integration-in-swiftui), and others, but the result is always the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Pandruz! Did you find a solution for your problem?

Comment: Hi! I still have the same code. Sometimes it works in test mode, but as of today it hasn't worked outside of test mode yet

Comment: thank you, Allmost the same problem here....